# glib g_malloc0() wants to allocate way too much memory

Tags: c, memory, malloc, out-of-memory, glib

Upon calling `addrtab = g_hash_table_new_full(g_int_hash, g_int_equal, g_free, NULL);` the execution aborts and the following is reported: `GLib-ERROR **: 15:23:58.535: ../../../glib/gmem.c:138: failed to allocate 11755944670652 bytes`. What puzzles me is the amount of memory requested.

Now a bit of details: I'm writing in C using glib-2.66 on Ubuntu 20.04. Commenting out the previously reported line solves the error entirely. `g_hash_table_new_full()` is used elsewhere in the program without causing any error.
For completeness I'm posting the function that calls that `g_hash_table_new_full()`

```
void addr_advertise (hash_node_t* alice, hash_node_t* bob){
    GHashTable* addrtab = NULL;

    if ((alice->data->key != bob->data->key) && !(alice->data->attackerid == 1 && bob->data->attackerid == 1)) {

        addrtab = g_hash_table_new_full(g_int_hash, g_int_equal, g_free, NULL);

        if(alice->data->attackerid == -1){
            //populate_honest_addr_table(addrtab, alice->data->known_peers);
        }
        else{
            //add_malicious_to_table(addrtab);
        }
        execute_addr(simclock + FLIGHT_TIME, alice, bob, 5, simclock, alice->data->key, addrtab);
    }
}
```

`addr_advertise` itself is called multiple times before causing the error.

As reported in gmem.c the error is caused by a `g_malloc0()` (line 138) that requests too much memory. How is it possible that g_malloc asks for so many bytes? Why previous executions of the same function work perfectly and most of all what could be the origin of the error?

Comment: I would say it is not this function who is causing the issue, but some bug corrupting something else before that. Please post [mcve].

Comment: Agreed with Eugene. Try running your code under valgrind to find other heap issues.